# I am facing issue in flutter_inappwebview

Tags: ios, flutter

I am facing the below issue when I try to call flutter module from native iOS app in flutter_inappwebview. When I run flutter app directly means it was working fine but issue happens when I call flutter module from native iOS app. Any one please help if you know any solutions for this..

Here is the error message:

```
Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(unregistered_view_type, A UIKitView widget is trying to create a PlatformView with an unregistered type: < com.pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview >, If you are the author of the PlatformView, make sure `registerViewFactory` is invoked.
See: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-views#on-the-platform-side-1 for more details.
If you are not the author of the PlatformView, make sure to call `GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register`., null)
#0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:652:7)
#1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:310:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      PlatformViewsService.initUiKitView (package:flutter/src/services/platform_views.dart:242:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      _UiKitViewState._createNewUiKitView (package:flutter/src/widgets/platform_view.dart:662:44)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem.
Tried multiple solutions online, like
flutter clean
flutter build clean
Adding keys into the Info.plist

However what really solved it was adding

```
  [InAppWebViewFlutterPlugin registerWithRegistrar:[registry registrarForPlugin:@"InAppWebView"]];
```

to the GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m

I don't know why it wasn't added there automatically during building.

Hope it helps.